# PLS-00201: Identifier "EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID" Must be Declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been working at this for over an hour now and I cannot figure it out...Here is my code. Any help is appreciated!

```
DECLARE 
    v_employee_id employees.employee_id % type;
    v_job employees.job_id % type;
BEGIN
   SELECT
      employee_id,
      job_id INTO v_employee_id,
      v_job 
   FROM
      employees 
   WHERE
      employee_id = 100;

    DECLARE 
        v_employee_id employees.employee_id % type;
        v_job employees.job_id % type;
    BEGIN
       SELECT
          employee_id,
          job_id INTO v_employee_id,
          v_job 
       FROM
          employees 
       WHERE
          employee_id = 103;
       dbms_output.put_line(outer_block.v_employee_id||' is a '||outer_block.v_job);
    END;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_employee_id || ' is a ' || v_job);
END;
```

Comment: Does the user you are logged in as having access to the employees table? Is the employees table in the same schema owned by the user logged in?

Comment: I am the user and yes I do have access to the schema showing the Employees Table.

Answer (score 1):

So the error your program actually produces is this:

> PLS-00201: identifier 'OUTER_BLOCK.V_EMPLOYEE_ID' must be declared

The line which hurls:

```
dbms_output.put_line(outer_block.v_employee_id || ' is a ' || outer_block.v_job);
```

You are attempting to display the first declaration of `v_employee_id` inside the nested block. However, there is no built-in `outer_block`, you need to declare it [as a label](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/block.htm#LNPLS01303).

So to make your code work you need to stick a label at the top:

```
<< outer_block >>
DECLARE 
    v_employee_id employees.employee_id % type;
    v_job employees.job_id % type;
BEGIN
    ....
```

Here is a [Live SQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f7o0nohzfsn5dbl4s0o2n2ow0) of the block working with a label.

---

Generally speaking it is not good practice to use the same name for different variables in nested scope. The labelling syntax allows it, but it is all too easy to forget the label and introduce a very hard to spot bug. Using different, meaningful variable names (e.g. `v_manager_id` for the outer block, `v_staff_id` for the nested block) is not only safer it also makes our code easier to understand.

Comment: So, I did that originally and still get a similar error of the following: 

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;

Comment: I apologize if I upset you...I have been trying to do this for a while now. I have used two different software to run the code and get the same error on both...One of the programs I am using is LiveSQL. So what am I supposed to do in order to be reasonable so that I don't offend someone? I am new to this and I didn't realize, requesting assistance would be offensive.

Comment: If that doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to show the actual code you're running and the error you are getting.

Answer (score -1):

remove spaces between `employees.employee_id` and the  `%`

here for example:

```
employees.employee_id % type;
```

this should be

```
employees.employee_id%type;
```

there are more errors here, but i'm answering your question.

Comment: The spaces look odd but actually they make no difference to whether the program runs.